# time evolution of Hamiltonian to generate the Bell pair

Tags: mathematics, quantum-operation, hamiltonian-simulation

Consider two different Hamiltonians: $H_1(t) = ZZ + \alpha(t)X_1 + \beta(t)X_2$ and $H_2(t) = XX + \alpha(t)Z_1 + \beta(t)Z_2$, where $\alpha(t)$ and $\beta(t)$ are time-dependent functions. Starting from $\lvert 00 \rangle$, why does time-evolution of $H_1(t)$ can't generate the Bell pair $= \frac{\lvert 00 \rangle + \lvert 11 \rangle}{\sqrt{2}}$, but $H_2(t)$ can? (assuming that evolution time $t = [0,T]$ isn't too short)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the matrix $H_2$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha+\beta & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & \alpha-\beta & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & \beta-\alpha & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & -(\alpha+\beta)
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
You can easily divide this into two subspaces. The first is spanned by $\{|00\rangle,|11\rangle\}$ on which your initial state is fully supported. Thus you're only trying to find functions $\alpha,\beta$ such that
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
\alpha+\beta & 1 \\
1 & -(\alpha+\beta)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
evolves $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$ into $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.

On the other hand, $H_1=(H\otimes H)H_2(H\otimes H)$ where $H$ is the Hadamard matrix. So, there *is* still a subspace structure, but it doesn't line up quite so nicely with our initial
$$
|00\rangle=\frac{1}{2}(|++\rangle+|--\rangle)+\frac12(|+-\rangle+|-+\rangle)
$$
and final states
$$
(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|++\rangle+|--\rangle).
$$
In particular, the two states are supported *by different amounts* by the two subspaces. But the point of evolution under this subspace structure is that the amount within each subspace is preserved.

---

Having gained this insight, there's a more elegant way of expressing this. For $H_2$, there is an operator $Z\otimes Z$ that it commutes with, and both initial and final states have the same expectation with that operator.

For $H_1$, the equivalent commutation is $X\otimes X$. The initial and final states have different expectation values, and hence cannot evolve into each other:
let $|\psi\rangle=e^{-iH_it}|\phi\rangle$ where $O$ is the operation that commutes with $H_i$. Then
$$
\langle\psi|O|\psi\rangle=\langle\phi|e^{iH_it}Oe^{-iH_it}|\phi\rangle=\langle\phi|e^{iH_it}e^{-iH_it}O|\phi\rangle=\langle\phi|O|\phi\rangle,
$$
i.e. the expectation value of the state with the commuting operator is preserved.